# Jest/Enzyme. Test that method is called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following `Select` component

```
getReason = () => {
        this.setState({
            productsRated: this.state.productsRated + 1
        });
};
...
<Select onChange={() => this.getReason()}>
</Select>
```

1. How to test that `getReason` has been called when I simulate value change on `<Select/>`?
2. Should I test private method at all or should I pass `getReason` method as a prop?
3. If I should pass as a prop how will I call `setState`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the better way is to validate against render's result.

It's hard to answer with code since we don't see how `this.state.productsRated` is used.

Assume we just output `this.state.productsRated`:

```
<Select onChange={this.getReason}
<span id="result">{this.state.productsRated}</span>
```

then our test would be

```
expect(someWrapper.find('#result').props().children).toEqual(2);
someWrapper.find(Select).props().onChange();
expect(someWrapper.find('#result').props().children).toEqual(3);
```

Also I don't see any profit of checking if *private* function has been called. When you test *implementation details* your tests become fragile and will break on changes that actually does not break application. Also it does not add confidence if app is ok or not.

PS and for state change when you use previous state value to calculate new one you *must* use functional version of `setState`. Using object version instead may(and probably will) [make bugs](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1).

Comment: Isn't it the point of unit testing to test single functions correct behaviour?

Comment: I see it that you are testing unit not a part of it. If it's single function that can be called as a function - it may sense to test it in isolation. but you don't test single code line from this function in isolation, right? here is a component, it does not really make sense if you test methods separately but it does not work well together. and vice versa: if it works as expected from this component it does not matter how internal methods are named and called.